# How to parse string to php array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an array string like this :

```
 Array
(
    [TRANSACTION_ID] => SFBT-U1005141804-18DZW
    [TRANSACTION_REFERENCE] => KRZTV
    [TRANSACTION_TYPE] => sale
    [TRANSACTION_STATUS_CODE] => SA
    [MERCHANT] => safebytes
    [AFFILIATE] =>
    [TRANSACTION_DATE] => 2014-05-10 18:04:51
    [CUSTOMER_AMOUNT] => 39.90
    [CUSTOMER_CURRENCY] => USD
    [CUSTOMER_NAME] => Robin Jennings
    [CUSTOMER_EMAIL] => nesiesurveys@aol.com
    [CUSTOMER_COUNTRY] => US
    [CUSTOMER_ADDRESS] =>
    [CUSTOMER_CITY] =>
    [CUSTOMER_REGION] => NJ
    [CUSTOMER_ZIP_POSTAL] => 07067
    [CUSTOMER_LANGUAGE] => EN
    [CUSTOMER_PHONE_NUMBER] =>
    [CUSTOMER_IP] => 96.225.124.15
    [CUSTOMER_IP_ADDRESS] => 96.225.124.15
    [PAYMENT_METHOD] => PAYPAL
    [SKU] => totalsystemcare/1pk1yr
    [ORDER_STATUS] => SUCCESS
    [NOTES] => NONE
    [PAYOUT_CURRENCY] => USD
    [PAYOUT_AMOUNT] => 36.13
    [TAXES_AMOUNT] => 0.00
    [VOID] => N
    [QUERY] => sku%5B0%5D%3Dtotalsystemcare%2F1pk1yr%26ec%3D2404%26os%3DWindows+7%26osb%3D64bit%26pr%3DIntel%28R%29+Core%28TM%29+i3+CPU+++++++M+380++%40+2.53GHz%26mb%3DDell+Inc.+0THYJV%26vc%3DIntel%28R%29+HD+Graphics%26ram%3D3.80+GB%26hd%3D465.76+GB%26isp%3D%26UID%3DE294A80C-28B1-444B-935A-2D58F8A034D2%26det_country%3DUnited+States%26cou
    [EVENT_ID] => 1
    [PROCESSOR] => SafeCart
    [BILL_AMOUNT] => 39.9
    [ITEMS] => [{"SKU":"totalsystemcare\/1pk1yr","PRICE":"39.90000","QUANTITY":1,"PAYOUT":"36.12695","TAX":0,"RECURRING":true}]
)
```

This string is written in the txt file . How I can parse it in the php array. I have already get it from file but I can't parse it into array.

can anyone help me ?

Comment: So you just want to turn the php array, written as a string imported from a file, back into a php array? Isn't your work laid out for you, especially if you know exactly how each item is formatted etc? I honestly have no formal experience with php but it seems like between http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and http://us2.php.net/preg_match you should be able to easily tackle your problem.

Comment: If you have control of the data at the point of export then you should be exporting it in a format that can easily be re-imported back into PHP.  You could serialize() or json_encode() it for starters, and then use unserialize() or json_decode() to import it back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your can use a `var_export` function for save PHP variables to file.

For example:

```
$data = array('Foo', 'Bar');
file_put_contents('filename.txt', '<?php return ' . var_export($data, true) . ';');

// And get this content
$data = include 'filename.txt';
```

Comment: @ZhukV `file_put_contents('vol/filename.txt', '<?php return ' . var_export($data, true).';');` use `;` in the end otherwise it will return error `unexpected $end in filename.txt`